# When I call 64-bit registry HKEY_CURRENT_USER from x86 application returns HKEY_USERS

Tags: c#, .net, registry, windows-7-x64

I am trying to access `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` from 64 bit registry for the following location `@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel"` using x86 built wix application through C# .net code. But it always rerun the key `HKEY_USERS` where i don't find the Excel key under Office\16.0. 
`HKEY_USERS` has only one subkey under office/16.0 is Outlook. First of all i am not looking into HKEY_USERS all i want to access `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`

My requirement is to add the application path under Trusted Locations of Excel in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.
My system specification is Windows 7 64 bit. The Wix application is built under the target framework x86.

I see the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` but not `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. I have tried the below options but it always returns `HKEY USERS` key.

1.

```
RegistryKey var = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry64);

RegistryKey reg2016Key = var.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel",RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree)
```

or

```
RegistryKey var = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry32);

RegistryKey reg2016Key = var.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel",RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree)
```

2.

```
public static class RegistryExtensions
{

    public enum RegistryHiveType
    {
        X86,
        X64
    }

    static Dictionary<RegistryHive, UIntPtr> _hiveKeys = new Dictionary<RegistryHive, UIntPtr> {
    { RegistryHive.ClassesRoot, new UIntPtr(0x80000000u) },
    { RegistryHive.CurrentConfig, new UIntPtr(0x80000005u) },
    { RegistryHive.CurrentUser, new UIntPtr(0x80000001u) },
    { RegistryHive.DynData, new UIntPtr(0x80000006u) },
    { RegistryHive.LocalMachine, new UIntPtr(0x80000002u) },
    { RegistryHive.PerformanceData, new UIntPtr(0x80000004u) },
    { RegistryHive.Users, new UIntPtr(0x80000003u) }
};

    static Dictionary<RegistryHiveType, RegistryAccessMask> _accessMasks = new Dictionary<RegistryHiveType, RegistryAccessMask> {
    { RegistryHiveType.X64, RegistryAccessMask.Wow6464 },
    { RegistryHiveType.X86, RegistryAccessMask.WoW6432 }
};

    [Flags]
    public enum RegistryAccessMask
    {
        QueryValue = 0x0001,
        SetValue = 0x0002,
        CreateSubKey = 0x0004,
        EnumerateSubKeys = 0x0008,
        Notify = 0x0010,
        CreateLink = 0x0020,
        WoW6432 = 0x0200,
        Wow6464 = 0x0100,
        Write = 0x20006,
        Read = 0x20019,
        Execute = 0x20019,
        AllAccess = 0xF003F
    }

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int RegOpenKeyEx(
      UIntPtr hKey,
      string subKey,
      uint ulOptions,
      uint samDesired,
      out IntPtr hkResult);

    public static RegistryKey OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive registryHive, RegistryHiveType registryType)
    {
        UIntPtr hiveKey = _hiveKeys[registryHive];
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 5)
        {
            RegistryAccessMask flags = RegistryAccessMask.QueryValue | RegistryAccessMask.EnumerateSubKeys | RegistryAccessMask.SetValue | RegistryAccessMask.CreateSubKey | _accessMasks[registryType];
            IntPtr keyHandlePointer = IntPtr.Zero;
            int result = RegOpenKeyEx(hiveKey, String.Empty, 0, (uint)flags, out keyHandlePointer);
            if (result == 0)
            {
                var safeRegistryHandleType = typeof(SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid).Assembly.GetType("Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeRegistryHandle");
                var safeRegistryHandleConstructor = safeRegistryHandleType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { typeof(IntPtr), typeof(bool) }, null); // .NET < 4
                if (safeRegistryHandleConstructor == null)
                    safeRegistryHandleConstructor = safeRegistryHandleType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(IntPtr), typeof(bool) }, null); // .NET >= 4
                var keyHandle = safeRegistryHandleConstructor.Invoke(new object[] { keyHandlePointer, true });
                var net3Constructor = typeof(RegistryKey).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { safeRegistryHandleType, typeof(bool) }, null);
                var net4Constructor = typeof(RegistryKey).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { typeof(IntPtr), typeof(bool), typeof(bool), typeof(bool), typeof(bool) }, null);
                object key;
                if (net4Constructor != null)
                    key = net4Constructor.Invoke(new object[] { keyHandlePointer, true, false, false, hiveKey == _hiveKeys[RegistryHive.PerformanceData] });
                else if (net3Constructor != null)
                    key = net3Constructor.Invoke(new object[] { keyHandle, true });
                else
                {
                    var keyFromHandleMethod = typeof(RegistryKey).GetMethod("FromHandle", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { safeRegistryHandleType }, null);
                    key = keyFromHandleMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { keyHandle });
                }
                var field = typeof(RegistryKey).GetField("keyName", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                if (field != null)
                    field.SetValue(key, String.Empty);
                return (RegistryKey)key;
            }
            else if (result == 2) // The key does not exist.
                return null;
            throw new Win32Exception(result);
        }
        throw new PlatformNotSupportedException("The platform or operating system must be Windows 2000 or later.");
    }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
var key64 = RegistryExtensions.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryExtensions.RegistryHiveType.X64);

RegistryKey reg2016Key  = key64.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel",RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree)
```

or

```
var keyX86 = RegistryExtensions.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryExtensions.RegistryHiveType.X86);

RegistryKey reg2016Key  = keyX86 .OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel",RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree)
```

Comment: This seems to be tagged incorrectly; The WiX tag is for the tool that builds Windows Installer MSI files.

Comment: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is just an alias for `HKEY_USERS\<sid>`

Comment: Also note that the key you're opening doesn't have separate 32-bit and 64-bit views, so there's no need to go to all that trouble, you can just access it directly.  We need a clearer problem statement.  What *exactly* goes wrong?

Comment: The key for the following path is always NULL Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Excel\Security\Trusted Locations", true) since it always returns the key HKEY_USERS.                                                                                  
 When i open the registry the following path exists Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Excel\Security\Trusted Locations", true) but always returns as NULL while accessing from x86 application.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean "always returns the key HKEY_USERS" ?  *What* always returns HKEY_USERS?  How can the key be NULL and HKEY_USERS at the same time?

Comment: Does the problem only occur when your code is run from WiX?  Are you sure it is running in the correct user context, and not, e.g., as local system or trusted user?

Comment: I created a sample x86 application which has the target framework as x86 and it works fine. I can get the path(RegistryKey reg2016Key = var.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel",RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree)) from the current user. But when i call the same method through x86 Wix Custom action, it return NULL value when i access same the key. I noticed that it is looking into HKEY_USERS node in the registry not HKEY_CURRENT_USER. This problem is occurring only through the Wix installer Custom Action.

Comment: I am running Wix source code as Administrator.